# setup-di-compile | PHP Fatal | Cannot declare class Magento\Framework\Console\Cli

Tags: magento-2.1, fatal-error, cli, setup-di-compile

When I try to run command `setup:di:compile` I get the following error:

```
[http]$ php-7.0 bin/magento setup:di:compile
The directory "/microcloud/domains/operm2/domains/domainname.co.uk/http/var/generation/Magento" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(/microcloud/domains/operm2/domains/domainname.co.uk/http/var/generation/Magento): Directory not empty#0 /microcloud/domains/operm2/domains/domainname.co.uk/http/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php(403): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteDirectory('/microcloud/dom...')
#1 /microcloud/domains/operm2/domains/domainname.co.uk/http/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/CompilerPreparation.php(68): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteDirectory('/microcloud/dom...')
#2 /microcloud/domains/operm2/domains/domainname.co.uk/http/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(74): Magento\Setup\Console\CompilerPreparation->handleCompilerEnvironment()
#3 /microcloud/domains/operm2/domains/domainname.co.uk/http/bin/magento(22): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct('Magento CLI')
#4 {main}

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class Magento\Framework\Console\Cli, because the name is already in use in /microcloud/domains/operm2/domains/domainname.co.uk/http/Cli.php on line 0

Fatal error: Cannot declare class Magento\Framework\Console\Cli, because the name is already in use in /microcloud/domains/operm2/domains/domainname.co.uk/http/Cli.php on line 0
```

Anyone came across this before? Running **Magento ver. 2.1.8**

Comment: as a fast fix: have you deleted the contents of var/generation, var/di and tried again?

Comment: Yes, that's working but once I regenerate the files in those directories, again the compilation fails so I'm looking for a solution rather than a quick fix :/ Thank you for your interest!

Comment: The first error is that a directory can not be deleted. Have you checked read/write permissions of your php user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is file permission / file ownership error. Basically the user that you are running `setup:di:compile` doesn't have the right permission to perform the code regeneration.

Please follow the dev doc for the correct settings:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html